# Eclipse/Logcat: how to avoid to loose all filters in logcat when restarting Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, filter, logcat

I use the "logcat filters" in order to be in position to analyse efficiently the messages displayed in LogCat.

```
Log.d("LOGCAT_FILTER","MESSAGE_DISPLAYED");
```

My problem is that all the filters I created in LogCat are deleted when I restart Eclipse... I waste a lot of time!

Two questions:

1. How to avoid to loose the logcat filters when restarting Eclipse?
2. How to avoid to have to reopen LogCat (Window=>Show View=>Other
   View=>LogCat) each time I restart Eclipse ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you can use the adb logcat command line in a terminal
[logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now, but for others...

LogCat is a view displayed in a perspective, in your workbench. Your workbench is saved when you exit Eclipse gracefully (meaning not a forced quit/shutdown of the application). Your filter will be saved, so long as your perspective and workbench is saved. To customize and save a perspective, use the Window menu. You also need to make sure that your saved filters are displayed by clicking on the button located at the upper right hand side of the LogCat window. This will solve both questions 1 and 2.  See also: Help --> Help Contents --> Workbench User Guide.